# Having problem inserting JQuery Date into List

Tags: 2007, date-time

**The situation**

I am using the Time Picker Addon (http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) to allow user to select a date in the format of YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.

The date is insert into a SharePoint 2007 List (where there is a column of type "Date & Time") using the SPServices (http://spservices.codeplex.com/).

However, I keep getting the following error message:

`<ErrorCode>0x81020014</ErrorCode><ErrorText>One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.</ErrorText>`

Appreciate any insight provided.

**The Code**

`<Field Name=\"Start Date\">" + Date.parse(startdate) + "</Field> \`

where the startdate is derived from the Time Picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```
function CreateNewItem( title, date, text ) {
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "UpdateListItems",
        async: false,
        batchCmd: "New",
        listName: "news_archive",
        valuepairs: [["Title", title], ["Date", date], ["Text", text], ["Image", "default.jpg"]],
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
          alert("completed");
        }
    });
}
```

Just change the date to your startdate and add/remove the valuepairs will do.